# Contiguous subarray and non-Contiguous

Tags: data-structures, computer-science, partition-problem

I was trying to solve [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/check-if-there-is-a-valid-partition-for-the-array/) on leetcode.

> You are given a 0-indexed integer array nums. You have to partition the array into one or more contiguous subarrays.
>
> We call a partition of the array valid if each of the obtained subarrays
> satisfies one of the following conditions:
> ...
>
> 1. The subarray consists of exactly 2 equal elements. For example, the subarray [2,2] is good.
> 2. The subarray consists of exactly 3 equal elements. For example, the subarray [4,4,4] is good.
> 3. The subarray consists of exactly 3 consecutive increasing element, For example, the subarray [3,4,5] is good

The problem is that there are two examples:

1. [4,4,4,5,6] - Valid (The array can be partitioned into the subarrays [4,4] and [4,5,6].)
2. [1,1,1,2] - Invalid

I expected example two to be valid as well since [1,1] and [1,1,1] both satisfy conditions 1 and 2 respectively.

So, why is it invalid?

Answer (score 0):

so there are three conditions and all the sub-array that you get after partition must satisfy at least one of the conditions.

for the example `[1,1,1,2]`, there are three ways you can make the partition and as you already know `[1] and [1,1,2]` do not satisfy any condition

the other two partitions left are `[1,1] and [1,2]` and `[1,1,1] and [2]`. In these situations, `[1,1]` and `[1,1,1]` indeed do satisfy one of the conditions but `[1,2]` and `[2]` do not satisfy any condition.

And for a partition of the array to be valid

> We call a partition of the array valid if EACH OF THE OBTAINED SUBARRAYS satisfies one of the following conditions

That is why [1,1,1,2] do not have a valid partition and should return `FALSE`